# comprehension with Nested loops

Tags: loops, nested, permutation

**I've to find how many different permutations are possible to create the sum of 65 using exactly three coins.**

given list :

- coins = [200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5]

what I've tried so far:

```
 len(set([x + y + z for x in coins for y in coins for z in coins if (x+y+z)%65 == 0]))
```

I've think I maybe should use the import function?

for example with a random list:

```
import itertools
len(list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3])))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your nested loops approach technically doesn't actually solve the problem since it will over-count by including multiples of your target sum 65. You will need to count only those which are exactly 65 in order to solve the problem -- see here:

```
coins = [200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5]
target = 65

original = len(set([x + y + z for x in coins for y in coins for z in coins if (x + y + z) % 65 == 0]))
print('Original:', original)  # prints 3

new = list(set([x + y + z for x in coins for y in coins for z in coins if (x + y + z) % target == 0])).count(target)
print('Ignoring multiples of 65:', new)  # prints 1
```

Now, for your second point, this is where it gets a little confusing. The above actually counts the number of *combinations* and **not** the number of permutations. In contrast, your original statement was for the number of permutations and your example with `itertools` also uses permutations. I'm not sure what your exact intention is, but `itertools` provides a method for both.

However, your example `len(list(itertools.permutations([1, 2, 3])))` would return a count of all permutations rather than only those which sum to your target value. So, if you do `len(list(itertools.permutations(coins)))`, the permutations would be of length 6 by default -- you have to supply a second argument to `itertools.permutations` for your target length of 3.

Hence, the following should work for you:

```
import itertools

perms = list(itertools.permutations(coins, 3))  # permutations of length 3
total_perms = len([perm for perm in perms if sum(perm) == target])  # count only those which sum to 65
print('Total permutations:', total_perms)  # prints 6
```

However, if you actually were interested in the number of *combinations* -- which is what the original nested loops method does, then you would have to use `itertools.combinations` instead:

```
combs = list(itertools.combinations(coins, 3))  # combinations of length 3
total_combs = len([comb for comb in combs if sum(comb) == target])  # count only those which sum to 65
print('Total combinations:', total_combs)  # prints 1
```

*Good luck!*